# Чтение текста из файла

Tags: c++

Не могу никак дойти до разумного решения данной проблемы, пытался использовать ifstream, fopen. 
[image: Чтение файла в c++]

```
       int main()
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char str[3500];
    if ((fp = fopen_s("C:\\Users\\I9609\\source\\repos\\lab5\\eng.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error of opening the file! ";
        exit;
    }
    fgets(str, 3500, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сигнатура функции:

```
errno_t fopen_s(   
   FILE** pFile,  
   const char *filename,  
   const char *mode   
);
```

Первым параметром необходимо передавать указатель на дескриптор файла:

```
FILE *fp;
errno_t err;
err  = fopen_s( &fp, "filename.txt", "r" );
if( err == 0 ) {  
   printf( "Файл открыт\n" );  
} else {  
   printf( "Ошибка\n" );  
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

"Если ничего не помогает - читай документацию" (с)

А там написано:

```
errno_t fopen_s(FILE**stream, const char* name. const chhar* mode);
```

(`restrict`ы опустил.)

Т.е. не

```
if ((fp = fopen_s("C:\\Users\\I9609\\source\\repos\\lab5\\eng.txt", "r")) == NULL)
```

а

```
errno_t err;
FILE * fp;
err = fopen_s(&fp,"C:\\Users\\I9609\\source\\repos\\lab5\\eng.txt","r");
if (err != 0) ....
```

Но еще лучше в С++ использовать `ifstream`...

Comment: Только что попытался переделать под "errno_t err;", файл не открывается :( Может нужно указать просто имя файла? Сейчас попробую через ifstream.